# c++ eclipse juno build error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm getting the following error with my C++ Eclipse Juno project, with Linux 64bits:

```
Error:
  description:Error 127 occurred while running autoreconf
  resource: MyProject
  location: -1
  type: Configure Problem
```

However my project builds successfully from command line.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this error, you need to install (GNU Autotools - which include autoconf and automake):

`sudo apt-get install automake`

If you "just want to write some C++" - select "**Executable**" instead of GNU AutoTools in the NEW, C++ project  (Hello World or Empty) menu.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366892/) may help. I think you would like to create executable project rather than GNU Autotools project.